# Библиотеки обработки изображений JS

Tags: javascript, изображения

Доброго времени суток.

Возникла необходимость обработки изображений, загружаемых в браузер. Необходимы манипуляции такие как обрезка, изменение яркости, контрастности,..т.п.

**Существуют ли какие-нибудь библиотеки для работы с изображениями?**

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию являются оффтопиком, описанный в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть библиотека Pixastic она использует canvas.А методов для обработки на js  я не встречал.
На всякий случай кину ссылку: https://habrahabr.ru/post/309430/